# Cocos3d class template missing

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I have installed cocos3d 0.7.2. I have developed sample projects. When i tried to add new file to my project, i couldn't find the cocos3d file templates in the template window.I could see only the cocos2d templates.
These are the screen shots,
[image]
[image]

Is that because of any installation errors ?
I had followed the steps of [this site](http://www.techipost.com/2011/02/20/installing-cocos3d-for-iphoneipad/)

What should i do ?

Thank you

Comment: this post is 2+ years old, don't expect it to work today. What about the official install instructions, have you tried those? Keep in mind that cocos3d 0.7 is only compatible with cocos2d v1.x

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am using cocos2d v1.1.0. What do you mean by official instructions ?

Comment: well i thought it's been two years they ought to have some install instructions, but alas no, none of that...

Comment: Is there any other way to add templates to it after installation ??

Comment: what i remeber is to install the cocos2d templates, then the cocos3d templates and providing the path to the cocos2d-iphone folder to the install-templates script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best place where you could get info to install this would be the readme file contained within the cocos3d package. The following instructions is an extract from the readme file. That would be the correct way to install it. It worked for me and it should have no issues. I would suggest you to reinstall it. Also the post you mentioned seems a bit old to me.

### Installation

The cocos3d framework is built on cocos2d 1.x. Before installing cocos3d,
you must download and install the cocos2d 1.x SDK from:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download

*** PLEASE NOTE THAT cocos3d 0.7.2 IS NOT COMPATIBLE WITH cocos2d 2.x.** 
**     BE SURE TO DOWNLOAD cocos2d 1.x FOR USE WITH cocos3d.          ***

Unzip the cocos3d distribution file (which you've probably already done,
otherwise you wouldn't be reading this document).

Open a Terminal session, navigate to the unzipped cocos3d distribution
directory and run the install-cocos3d script as follows:

./install-cocos3d.sh -f -2 "path-to-cocos2d-sources"

For example:

./install-cocos3d.sh -f -2 "../../cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-1.1"

The cocos2d source code must be available and identified using the -2 switch so that the
installer can link the cocos2d libraries to the cocos3d templates and demo projects.

If you encounter 'rsync' errors during installation, it's typically because you are trying
to run the installer without first navigating to the cocos3d distribution directory.
Be sure to run the installer from the cocos3d distribution directory.

That's it!

**Note: Again the above extract is a part of the readme file which is in the root folder of your cocos3d directory.**

I would also suggest you to read the readme file, as it contains a lot of valuable info.

**EDIT:**  There is nothing wrong with the install.
What you want can be achieved as follows

1) Select new file from navigator.

2) In the following window under iOS, select Cocoa Touch.

3) Select Objective-C class from the templates in that list.

4) Fill in the appropriate class name and under "subclass of" field type in the parent class  name from where you need to inherit (Ex: CCNode) and click next.

5) That will be the template file you needed along with the necessary .h and .m files.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i am sorry to say that i followed the  guidelines in the readme file and still i ve the same problem.

Comment: macm58:cocos2d-iphone-1.1-RC0 user$ ./install-templates.sh -u -f
cocos2d-iphone template installer
Installing Xcode 4 cocos2d iOS template
----------------------------------------------------
...creating destination directory: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d/
...copying cocos2d files
...copying cocoslive files
...copying TouchJSON files
...copying CocosDenshion files
...copying CocosDenshionExtras files
...copying FontLabel files
...copying template files
done!Installing Xcode 4 Chipmunk iOS template
----------------------------------------
...copying Chipmunk files
done!

Comment: Previous one is cocos2d installation log. Here is the cocos3d installation log,

Comment: macm58:cocos3d 0.7.2 user$ ./install-cocos3d.sh -f -2 /Users/user/Desktop/cocos2d-iphone-1.1-RC0 
cocos3d installer

Linking cocos2d libraries to workspace
...linking cocos2d files
...linking FontLabel files
...linking CocosDenshion files
...linking cocoslive files
...linking cocoslive dependency files
done!
...creating Xcode 4 cocos3d template folder

Comment: Installing Xcode 4 cocos3d iOS template
...creating destination directory: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos3d/cocos3d Application.xctemplate
...copying cocos3d Application template files
...creating destination directory: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos3d/cocos3d Application.xctemplate/Resources
...creating destination directory: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos3d/cocos3d-base.xctemplate
...copying cocos3d-base template files
...creating destination directory:

Comment: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos3d/cocos3d-lib.xctemplate
...copying cocos3d-lib template files
...copying cocos3d files to cocos3d-lib template
done!

Comment: WAIT THAT IS PERFECTLY NORMAL.I just saw your pic now. What do you mean by template files? If you want to create a new class just open add file and in the template window select cocoa touch and then select Objective-C class. in the following window enter the "subclass of" field to whichever parent class you want. YOUR ABOVE PIC IS PERFECTLY NORMAL AND YOUR COCOS3D INSTALL IS WORKING FINE. Hope you got my point:-)

Answer (score 0):

Your installation is successful. You can add class as custom by adding class normally. ie. by adding **objective-c class** in **cocoatouch** section in add new class window. There **wont be** any special templates for adding custom class in cocos3d.